# Getting error "avoid mutate props directly" and displaying button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework

i getting error message when i am passing my prop to component. This props is a to displaying button element in payment. Certain component must not show this button but when i pass the prop all the component that uses this button is hidden here are my code for the parent. My problem is same as this (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/using-v-if-to-render-one-template-or-another-based-on-a-props) and the solution does not work for me

```html
<payment :sharedButton="false"><payment>
```

this is my payment.vue button

```
<div class="col-lg-auto" v-if="unpaid.qr_code === 1 && sharedButton === true">
  <q-btn glossy
    size="md"
    :label="$t('Common.GetQrCode.Button')"
    @click="makePayment(unpaidIndex, true)" color="positive"
  >
  </q-btn>
</div>
```

```js
export default{
  props: {
    sharedButton: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
```

here is the logic that when the sharedButton is false then hide it but when the sharedButton is true then show the button

Expected result:
Button in certain component is hidden

Current Result:
All the component with the button is hidden and get avoid mutate props directly

Comment: Can you please try to align your booleans and strings? Looks like you have a default value of Boolean (true), but you hand in a STRING "false"

Comment: What does `makePayment` look like?

Comment: @MattU it just a making transaction, it just redirect user to make payment page

Comment: You probably have a problem with prop attribute casing. Typically, you need to use kebab-case in your template, ie `:shared-button="false"`

Comment: @Phil i tough props cannot receive kebab cases

Comment: @atifazrin please see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case. You can name your prop `sharedButton` but when you use it in your template, you should use `:shared-button`

Comment: @Phil thx i forget about this

Comment: Somewhere you are changing the value of this prop. e.g. `this.sharedButton = true`. Could you please include that code in the question? It would also be helpful if you could include the full error message as that will help us to confirm exactly which prop you are changing.

Comment: The symptoms make me think you might have something like `if (this.sharedButton = false) {` in your code, where you've written `=` instead of `===`. This is a wild guess but it's an easy mistake to make and it would cause the prop to be modified and all the buttons to disappear.

Comment: @skirtle i tough that was too but still giving me the same result. My problem is same this link but could't solve https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/using-v-if-to-render-one-template-or-another-based-on-a-props

Answer (score 0):

so i solve the my problem apparently i cannot directly assigned  instead i declare a variable called isHidden in data()

```
data(){
   isHidden : false;
}
```

then declare it by `<payment-tab sharedButton = "isHidden">`

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the issue as you are directly mutating the prop in the child component and the parent isn't notified about the same. A simple way to solve this is to sync the value of prop in the child and the parent component. So, you can change the value directly in the parent component and since props are reactive the new value of the prop would directly get assigned to the child component.

I am assuming that you'd have an option to change the value back to true in your parent component.

```
<payment :sharedButton.sync="sharedButton"><payment>
```

(The second sharedButton would be the value kept in the parent component)

Now, when you want to change the prop inside the child just use

```
this.$emit('update:sharedButton', false)
```